# find modified files recursively and copy with directory preserving directory structure

Tags: shell-script, find, file-copy

I want to find images, from a directory, that were added in last 1 year and copy them to a new directory preserving original folder structure.

I am using find but it is not copying anything. is there any way it can be done using 1 line command?

`find  image/* -mtime +356 -exec cp  {} modified-last-year/ \;`

I am in the image directory when running this command and i want to only search image folder recursively.

[EDIT] 
After the two answers I did following.
 1. `find  image/* -mtime +356 | cpio -pd /target_dir`

 I get 0 Blocks.

2. `find /full/path/to/image -mtime 365 -type f ( "-name *.jpg -o -name *.gif ) -execdir cp {} /full/path/to/image_target_dir/modified-last-year \;`

   AND
3. `find /full/path/to/image -mtime 365 -type f -execdir cp {} /full/path/to/image_target_dir/modified-last-year \;`

    Nothing copied.

   AND simply find to get count of files with and without -type f.
4. `find /full/path/to/image -mtime 365 -type f | wc -l` 

   i get 0.

   I could verify that there are indeed files with in image dir and in sub directories which were added in last 1 yr. infact there should be more than 200 images.

   [EDIT 2]
   I have to also exclude one directory from find so the following code worked fine.

   Thanks to 1st answer, i was able to create this.

   `find  /full/path/to/image/* -path /full/path/to/image/ignored_dir -prune -o -print -mtime -365 | cpio -pd /full/path/to/target_dir/modified-last-year`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use find and `cpio` in passthrough mode:

```
 find  image/ -mtime -365 | cpio -pd /target_dir
```

EDIT: removed unnecessary * from the find path.

Comment: For some reason I get 0 Block. I could verify that there are indeed files with in image dir and in sub directories which were added in last 1 yr. infact there should be more than 200 images.

Comment: The nice thing about using find and cpio is that you can test that the find command returns the desired files, before piping to cpio. What does 'find  image/ -mtime +356' return?

Comment: With a plus sign it was giving no results. So i went out of image dir one level up and executed this command and it worked just fine. Is there a way to exclude one particular directory?

Comment: Also does it check -mtime for subdirectories as well?

Comment: Okay so i was able to finally successfully execute this...

` find  /full/path/to/image/* -path /full/path/to/image/ignored_dir -prune -o -print -mtime -365 | cpio -pd /full/path/to/target_dir/modified-last-year` Also added for ignored dir and everything worked out well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you already are in directory `image`, then `find  image/* ...` spells trouble. Instead for relative paths, either use `find .` (etc)  where the "." signifies the present directory and its sub-directory tree, or better yet, use absolute paths:

```
$ find /full/path/to/imagedir -mtime -365 -execdir cpio -pdv {} /absolute/path/to/targetdir \;
```

Provided you have proper permission to do so, the above should copy all files modified more recently than 365*24 hours (before today) in yr target-directory, while preserving the directory structure.

Option `-execdir` is safer than `-exec`, does the same but is executed from the directory where the selected file is found.

You can further restrict the files being parsed by find by specifying the options `-type f \( "-name \*.jpg -o -name \*.gif \)` in the above cmd.

cpio's options are:

```
-p for passthrough (does not make an archive out of the set of dound files)
-d to preserve the directory structure
-v to visualize files being copied
```

Look at the manual page for `find`, at https://www.gnu.org/software/cpio/manual/cpio.html for the complete `cpio` online manual, and remember [www.startpage.com](https://www.startpage.com) is a friend that does not make you the product when you look for answers.

Comment: For some reason I get 0 files. I could verify that there are indeed files with in image dir and in sub directories which were added in last 1 yr. infact there should be more than 200 images. 
I did `$ find /full/path/to/image -mtime 365 -type f \( "-name \*.jpg -o -name \*.gif \) -execdir cp {} /full/path/to/image_target_dir/modified-last-year \;` and I also did just simple `find /full/path/to/image -mtime 365 | wc -l` but i get 0.

Comment: @SyedMudabbir: very odd. Can you tell us the exact absolute paths you use to issue yr cmd ? Then execute `$ find /full/path/to/image -mtime 365 -type f \( "-name \*.jpg -o -name \*.gif \); echo $?` and print out the resulting 10 first lines if any in an EDIT in yr original question. There is something iffy going on.

Comment: I was running this command while in image dir itself. The target dir was also in image dir. So i moved target dir out of image, went up one level ..  and I just modified the command and made -mtime 365 as -mtime -365. I was using absolute path for both dirs. This worked but only issue was it was not including parent dirs and was copying only files.

Comment: @SyedMudabbir: I did think that something along that line was causing trouble. To preserve directory structure, do (as suggested by bjerre above): `$ find /full/path/to/imagedir -mtime -365 -execdir cpio -pd {} /absolute/path/to/targetdir \;`. `cpio`'s options are `-p` for passthrough (does not make an archive out of the set of dound files) and `-d`to preserve the directory structure. Sorry for the typo on `-365`. My bad !